# How to use Ansible docker_swarm to add master nodes

Tags: docker, ansible, docker-swarm, ansible-2.x

I am trying to add three master nodes with Ansible.

```
- name            : Init a new swarm with default parameters
  community.general.docker_swarm:
    advertise_addr: "{{ docker_swarm_master_ip }}"
    state         : present
  register        : swarm_info
  when            : 
                  - ansible_eth1.ipv4.address == docker_swarm_master_ip

- name            : Add master nodes
  community.general.docker_swarm:
    advertise_addr: docker_swarm_master_ip
    remote_addrs  : "{{ swarm_master_nodes }}"
    join_token    : "{{ swarm_info.swarm_facts.JoinTokens.Manager }}"
    state         : join    
  when            : 
                  - inventory_hostname == "node1"
```

It is not adding the nodes in the list `swarm_master_nodes`
No errors. node1 is the leader where the swarm was initialized.

How to use it correctly. The documentation is not very clear.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According documentation:

```
- name: Init a new swarm with default parameters
  community.general.docker_swarm:
    state: present

- name: Add nodes
  community.general.docker_swarm:
    state: join
    advertise_addr: 192.168.1.2
    join_token: SWMTKN-1--xxxxx
    remote_addrs: [ '192.168.1.1:2377' ]
```

You do not have to `advertise_addr` when you are initializing a new swarm cluster. Also, `remote_addrs` should be the IP address of the master node.

So, that should be what you want:

```
- name            : Init a new swarm with default parameters
  community.general.docker_swarm:
    state         : present
  register        : swarm_info
  when            : 
                  - ansible_eth1.ipv4.address == docker_swarm_master_ip

- name            : Add master nodes
  community.general.docker_swarm:
    advertise_addr: "{{ node1 }}"
    remote_addrs  : ["{{ docker_swarm_master_ip }}"]
    join_token    : "{{ swarm_info.swarm_facts.JoinTokens.Manager }}"
    state         : join    
  when            : 
                  - inventory_hostname == "node1"
```

Comment: Without `addvertise_addr` how can I specify exactly which node to be the leader ? Yes, it will run on the first remote host it runs. When your machine have many network interfaces it needs to be specified. It will complain otherwise.  `remote_addrs` should also be IP of the master node ? Then where will it find the nodes to join the swarm ?  The documentation says `Remote address of one or more manager nodes of an existing Swarm to connect to.
Used with state=join.`.   `advertise_addr` must be the `swarm init` node. `remote_addrs` contain addr for nodes to join, isn't it ?

Comment: I didn't find anything about that.
What I did was check some codes from Ansible galaxy to see how they are implementing docker swarm using ansible. I hope that [one](https://github.com/thomasjpfan/ansible-docker-swarm-role/blob/master/tasks/cluster.yml) may help you.

Comment: It is the paramter documnetation. None the less, I appreciate your time. Thanks for the link that helped.